# Reducing processing time reading spatial data

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I have a feature class I wanted to read as a Spatially enabled dataframe:

```
from arcgis.features import GeoAcessor

df_teig = GeoAccessor.from_featureclass(feature_class_path)
```

The dataframe has 17 columns including the geometry column, and has about 6 million rows of polygon data. Reading the data alone takes 2 hours. I was wondering if there's any way to make the process run faster or if there are better alternatives to read spatial data to dataframe.